# Ansible GitHub add deploy key to Github repo

Tags: github, ansible

When I try to add my server's ssh key to the list of deploy keys for my Github repo I get the following error:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "error": "Not Found", "http_status_code": 404, "msg": "GitHub repository does not exist"}
```

[As far as I can tell I've followed the directions here exactly](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/github_deploy_key_module.html)

Here's the tasks I'm trying to execute:

```
- name: Get Public SSH Key
  slurp:
    src: "/home/{{deploy_user}}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
  register: pubkey

- name: Add deploy user's ssh as deploy key
  community.general.github_deploy_key:
    owner: "{{ github_user_name }}"
    repo: "{{  github_project_name  }}"
    name: "{{ github_key_name }}"
    key: "{{ pubkey['content'] | b64decode }}"
    token: "{{ github_auth_token }}"
    read_only: yes
```

The documentation simply uses the word 'example' for the repo. I interpreted that to mean all thats required is the name of the repository from the url `https://github.com/user_name/example_repo` in this case the repo name would be `example_repo`.

What is the expected format for the repo name?  At this point I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your right. You can always run the command with `-vvvv` to see how Ansible will treat parameter info you are passing in the module.

Comment: Just mind that `owner` and your GitHub username might be two different things, for example, in the case the repo is owned by an organisation, rather.

Comment: Thanks for the reminders, -vvvv while verbose doesn't show url formation, rather it seems like it's make a request of an API with attached parameters like: username, repo, etc.  Also, I am able to confirm that the owner is definitely me, and I'm able to git clone repos using a combo of my user name and repo name.